# Sum of column based on a condition a R

Tags: r, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I would like to print out total amount for each date so that my new dataframe will have date and and total amount columns.
My data frame looks like this

| permitnum | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 6/1/2022 | na |
| ascas | 30.00 |
| olic | 40.41 |
| 6/2/2022 | na |
| avrey | 17.32 |
| fev | 32.18 |
| grey | 12.20 |

any advice on how to go about this will be appreciated

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You seem to have mixed data types in columns which is a problem. How did you import the data? It's better to share a `dput()` so we know exactly what's in the data.frame and how it's coded rather than using HTML tables for sharing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another `tidyverse` option, where I convert to date (and then reformat), then we can fill in the date, so that we can use that to group. Then, get the sum for each date.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(permitnum = format(as.Date(permitnum, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
  fill(permitnum, .direction = "down") %>% 
  group_by(permitnum) %>% 
  summarise(total_amount = sum(as.numeric(amount), na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
  permitnum  total_amount
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 06/01/2022         70.4
2 06/02/2022         61.7
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(permitnum = c("6/1/2022", "ascas", "olic", "6/2/2022", 
"avrey", "fev", "grey"), amount = c("na", "30.00", "40.41", "na", 
"17.32", "32.18", "12.20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. Split the data by the date marked by a row with a number, then summarize the total in amount and combine the date and all rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read_table("permitnum    amount
6/1/2022    na
ascas   30.00
olic    40.41
6/2/2022    na
avrey   17.32
fev 32.18
grey    12.20")

dat |>
  group_split(id = cumsum(grepl("\\d", permitnum))) |>
  map_dfr(\(x){
    date <- x$permitnum[[1]]
    x |>
      slice(-1) |>
      summarise(date = date,
                total_amount = sum(as.numeric(amount)))
  })
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   date     total_amount
#>   <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 6/1/2022         70.4
#> 2 6/2/2022         61.7
```